# Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 0 (RC0 ) Setup

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

When I Install SQL Server 2016 I receive [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXsx9.png):

> The operating system on this computer or its service pack level does not meet the minimum requirements for SQL Server 2016

How I Solve This ?

My System : Windows 7 64 bit, Service Pack 1

Answer (score 2):

Windows 8 & Server 2012 are the minimum supported OS versions for SQL Server 2016 so you're out of luck.

See [Operating System Requirements](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143506(v=sql.130).aspx#hwswr).